# This is my form, how can I hide my form and display thanks note after form submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, cloudpage, bootstrap

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <title>My Form</title>
 <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
 <div class="row setup-content" id="">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Name</label>
 <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="Name" name="Name"> </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Email</label>
 <input type="email" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="email@example.com" id="email" name="email">
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Title</label>
          <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="Title" name="Title">
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Department</label>
          <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Department" id="Department" name="Department">
        </div>
 <button id="myButton" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-left" type="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you should summarize the problem, put more details and show what you tried so you will have more chances getting an answer than just throwing your code here. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea for this is that you can redirect with a flag parameter from the targeted page to the original form page. From there, the form page can check the flag parameter and decide which content it will show.

For example:

In the targeted page (also a cloud page), you can use a flag parameter "success" and redirect to the form page with the flag parameter

```
%%[
    /* Process your data */

    /* redirect to the form page with the flag parameter */
    set @formPage = "Your submit form URL"
    Redirect(Concat(@formPage, "?success=1"))
]%%
```

In your form page, check and decide the content to show:

```
%%[
    set @success = RequestParameter("success")
    if @success == 1 then
]%%
<!-- Put your thank you message here -->
%%[ else ]%%
<!-- Put your submit form here -->
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Thank you Duc Le. This helped!